# Created an Asp.net Core Web API that return PDF File and on PDF Viewer or Browser loading very slow

Tags: c#-4.0, asp.net-core-webapi

i was trying to create an EPaper PDF viewer using react js as front-end and back-end asp.net core web api, here my API code that return pdf file.

```
[HttpGet]
public async Task<IActionResult> Get(int id)
{
   var epaper = await _context.EPaperFilePages.FirstOrDefaultAsync(x => 
                  x.Id == id);
        if (epaper == null)
        {
            return NotFound();
        }
        var inputPath = $"{_hostingEnvironment.WebRootPath}\\EPaper\\{epaper.PageFileName}";
        MemoryStream stream = new MemoryStream();
        using (FileStream fileStream = new FileStream(inputPath, FileMode.Open))
        {
            await fileStream.CopyToAsync(stream);
            await fileStream.FlushAsync();
        }
        stream.Position = 0;
        return File(stream, System.Net.Mime.MediaTypeNames.Application.Pdf);
 }
```

when i use this api in browser or react code it was loading very slow minimum it was taking 1 min to load the file.

please suggest is there any way to load pdf file faster using any packages or how should i improve my code that loads the pdf file faster.

Answer (score 0):

You can query like `detail = Parking.joins(:cars).select('parkings.*, count(cars.parking_id) as Alloted, no_of_places - count(parking_id) as Remaining, cars.*, cars.id as car_id').group('place_name')`

Answer (score 0):

`joins` will do an inner join and leave off parking records where there are no cars.

Instead, can you do an `includes`?  Or a `.left_outer_joins`

```
detail = Parking.left_outer_joins(:cars).
         select('parking_id, place_name, no_of_places, count(parking_id) as Alloted, no_of_places - count(parking_id) as Remaining').
         group('place_name')
```